# How to read jsonb from Postgres using the Jsonb library

Tags: java, json, postgresql, kotlin, jsonb

I am trying to read a jsonb field from a postgre table. I have tried to read it as a Jsonb type using the Jsonb library in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
data class Test(
    @Id
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    val candidates: Jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(),

)
```

But apparently, it doesnt build giving me the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jsonb]
```

I have found a few posts and answer. But none of them are apparently using [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api/1.0) api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the PostgreSQL `jsonb` type does not correspond to the JSR-367 Java API you're using. That one serialization tooling. The one you need is JSR-353 [javax.json:javax.json-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api), the reference implementation of which is [org.glassfish:javax.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json).

Meaning instead of

```
val candidates: Jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()
```

You should use

```
val candidates: JsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().build()
```

And the simplest way to make Hibernate (which the error message reveals you are using) 5.1, 5.2 or 5.3 recognize JSR-353 objects, is to add [this type-contributor library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-json-contributor) to your project dependencies. Hibernate 5.1 is the minimal required version, where as as of 6.0 (or possibly as early as 5.4) the type system will be redesigned and made incompatible.

Oh, and you won't need the `@Type` annotation with this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it builds. But it doesn't read. Following is the error message
`nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [[]] value by reflection`.
the data stored in the field is an Array of String.

Comment: `Can not set final javax.json.JsonObject field to org.glassfish.json.JsonArrayBuilderImpl$JsonArrayImpl`

Comment: Well, then use `javax.json.JsonArray`. Also, it shouldn't be final, because once you create the JsonArray you can't alter it. And since you're using this as a workaround for arrays, I would recommend my [array type-contributor](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor) instead, which allows you to use string arrays and non-primitive number arrays. That is, unless you need JSON for other reasons.

Comment: Oh, and that package covers the default JVM classes in `java.lang.*` and `java.time.*`. However it is extensible, if you follow the example of the `with-arrays` branch of the json contributor https://github.com/mopano/hibernate-json-type/blob/with-arrays/README.md

Comment: JsonArray works perfectly. I tried that before but did not have the correct dependency. Thanks a lot :)